# Feign Custom decoder: ClassNotFoundException

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud-feign

I'm trying to create a custom retryefor my feign client and I have this configuration

```
public class CustomClientConfiguration {

  @Bean
  public ErrorDecoder errorDecoder() {
    return new FeingErrorDecoder();
  }

  @Bean
  public Retryer retryer() {
    return new FeignCustomRetryer();
  }
}
```

```
@FeignClient(value = "customclient", url = "${url}", configuration = CustomClientConfiguration.class)
public interface CustomClient {
...
}
```

```
feign:
  client:
    config:
      default:
        errorDecoder: com.testfeign.FeignErrorDecoder
        retryer: com.testfeign.FeignCustomRetryer
```

And when I try to run an integration test, i get

```
Description:

Failed to bind properties under 'feign.client.config.default.error-decoder' to java.lang.Class<feign.codec.ErrorDecoder>:

    Property: feign.client.config.default.error-decoder
    Value: com.testfeign.FeignErrorDecoder
    Origin: class path resource [application.yml] - 186:23
    Reason: failed to convert java.lang.String to java.lang.Class<feign.codec.ErrorDecoder> (caused by java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.testfeign.FeignErrorDecoder)

Action:
Update your application's configuration
```

Not sure what i'm doing wrong as all the docs i've found are doing this in a similar manner.

I tried replacing the `default` with `customclient`, still the same error, kinda obviously though.

As a dependecy I have

```
...
    <dependency>
      <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-openfeign</artifactId>
      <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
    </dependency>
...
  <parent>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <relativePath/>
    <version>2.6.3</version>
  </parent>
  <properties>
    <spring-cloud.version>2021.0.3</spring-cloud.version>
  </properties>
```